# how to create a static iOS library for unity from an existing xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, unity-game-engine

I have a fully functional iOS project. I would like to create a static library from it, that I can use some of the methods in Unity.
Is that even possible? Or do I have to create a new Xcode project as a static library and copy paste everything? I am using the latest versions of unity and Xcode.

nice greets

Answer (score 0):

This should help:
http://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/creating-static-library-in-ios-app-development/

Let me know if there are some other issues related to this. Copying the whole code doesn't make sense, the static library will reduce the complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But I can't see how I can create a library from an existing iOS project in this article.

Comment: The idea is to create a ".a" file which is in turn a static library you were asking about.

That ".a" file needs to be included in your new project wherein you want to reuse the Unity framework methods. Just make sure you follow all the steps as the tutorial seems to be comprehensive and self explanatory.

Happy coding !